# Kif test doesn't find UITableView sometimes

Tags: kif

I am running some iOS Kif tests that fail about 50% of the time. I get the following message

The step timed out after 10.00 seconds: Could not find view matching: accessibilityIdentifier == "Search Results Table"

```
[tester waitForCellAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] inTableViewWithAccessibilityIdentifier:@"Search Results Table"];
```

Does anybody have any idea as to why it only happens sometimes?

Comment: Are you using Xcode6 Beta with the iOS8.0 simulator? We've seen this happen on iOS8 sim sometimes but it's stable on the iOS7 sim.

Comment: We are not using iOS8.0 yet but will be soon so I will keep that in mind.

Comment: OK, in that case, here are the things we usually try:
1) Make sure that the accessibility *identifier* is set.  Not the accessibility *label*.  Assuming this is fine for you.
2) Try to make sure it's set after view loads.  put a breakpoint and make sure the value is there. Assuming also this is fine for you.
3) See if there are differences between running a single test and running all the tests at once to make sure there aren't persistent data from other tests affecting your current one.
4) If all else fails, I just put a breakpoint and step in to KIF.
Good luck!

Comment: @plluke - thanks so much, your comment helped me realize that we were setting the accessibilityLabel, and not the accessibilityIdentifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we found was to switch off the animation. The animation was effecting the tests even when we used 'waitForTimeInterval'. I think it would be better if we didn't have to switch off the animation but at least we can continue testing now.

[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading stuff from the web?

Try to add

```
[tester waitForTimeInterval: 3.0];
```

before that line.

Answer (score 0):

Do You really set the accessibilityIdentifier not the accessibilityLabel ?

check this link, tableview should use accessibilityIdentifier
https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/489